# Forward port from 80 to 9000 not working

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, iptables

I'm trying to host an app on Ubuntu 14.04 and want to redirect traffic from 80 to 9000.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to 9000
```

Have run these commands but nothing...

```
lala:/etc/init.d$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any suggestions? I've been doing this for a while but have restarted the server and it's no longer working hmhm

It is working if I go to www.domain:9000

Comment: Just for completeness could you add the output of `sudo iptables -L -vt nat` thanks.

Comment: @squarebear thx, this showed me that I had some 80->8080 rule applied before mine. c/p issue :) works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo iptables -L -vt nat
```

showed me how many PREROUTING rules I have applied to iptables and with

```
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING 1
```

I've delete accidentally copied routing rule 80->8080.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Uncomplicated Firewall, rather than trying to make your chain rules directly. Check out the usage of ufw here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html

Add before filter section in /etc/ufw/before.rules(top of file):

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 9000
COMMIT
```

Also, check your sysctl settings:

```
sudo vim /ufw/sysctl.conf
```

make sure that port forwarding is enabled.

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Save the file,then restart ufw.

Comment: added it, disabled/enabled ufw but nothing. Didn't see any change. Ufw status doesn't show the redirect (should it be visible there?)

Comment: Check your sysctl settings:

sudo vim /ufw/sysctl.conf

make sure that port forwarding is enabled.

net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

save the file, and restart ufw